# Life cycle Hook in vueJs

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I am using Firebase auth for user authentication, and Firestore for database, but I am not able to sync between user and its campaigns.

```
campaigns: firestoreAction(({ bindFirestoreRef, getters }) => {
   return bindFirestoreRef(
      'campaigns',
      firebase.firestore().collection(`user_profile`).doc(getters.user.data.id).collection("campaigns"))
}),
```

**and getting this error:**

> vue.esm.js?a026:628 [Vue warn]: Error in created hook: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of null"

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

**TypeError** means your are accessing a property of an object that is null.

May be your **getters.user.data** is **null** and you are trying to access id on **null**.

Please print your **getters.user.data** in browser console.

Comment: yes. getters.user.data is null as this action called before completing fetch user.

Comment: I can't explain you in more detail without look into store file but my suggestion is you should create one action that fetch users data when you received response then call  campaigns action. In this way you will get user data first.

Answer (score 0):

it is just like you are not able to get values in your getters, try to mutate the user object in vuex properly and then set the object in getters, may be you are not getting proper response or if getting then may be could not be able to get in this component .

Comment: i have set user on authchange. but issue is. this campaign action is call before fetching user.